# Is there a term for how word pronunciation changes based on a sort of erosion?

Tags: pronunciation

I remember in graduate school a professor using a word that sounded like "Hypochoriate" that meant the erosion of a sound based on common usage. I think! I liked the word but can't remember what it was, or even if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: Well, "[hypocoristic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypocoristic#English)" means "relating to baby/childish talk". Could this be what the prof meant?

Comment: That may be what he meant. I thought it was a specific term relating to the process by which a word, through usage, gets eroded into something shorter. He was probably speaking metaphorically, as Faulkner scholars often do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word  in question might be

> hypoarticulation

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypoarticulation)
This term, *hypoarticulation* is not recorded in many dictionary sources. However it is used in some academic works [English pronunciation in a globalized world](https://books.google.com/books?id=QJ37CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT149&lpg=PT149&dq=hypoarticulation%20definition&source=bl&ots=y-ejx_CLEP&sig=LvG7lUelR7N83ZaM4ZuaVBRMt3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj24Jzx0I7XAhWI4CYKHWXwCq0Q6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=hypoarticulation%20definition&f=false)

I think this word fits the question, although there may be others.